# Update the value in the file by shell

Tags: shell

I face a problem with shell scripting. I have a file that stores variable values. I want to update the values of variables through a script. Can you please suggest the easiest method for this?

`VAR.ENV` file contains

```
FLAG=TRUE
```

I want to update the value as below by scripting

```
FLAG=FALSE
```

Note  : There are so many variables exist in this file.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e 's/^FLAG=.*/FLAG=FALSE/' thefile
```

Provided your file indeed has a line like this. You may need more work if the format varies.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F= -v OFS='=' '{print $1, ENVIRON[$1]}' VAR.ENV > tmp && 
mv tmp VAR.ENV
```

Without (directly) using a temp file:

```
perl -i -F= -lape '$_ = $F[0] . "=" . $ENV{$F[0]}' VAR.ENV
```